# How to read BigQuery view using BigQuery REST API?

Tags: api, rest, view, google-bigquery

I have BQ table `configuration` in `MAPPINGS` and its view `config_vw` in `SHARED_VIEWS` data set.

Now I am trying to read the table and its view using REST API URI.

The table request `GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/data-dev2/datasets/MAPPINGS/tables/configuration/data` is responding correctly.

But when I am doing `GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/data-dev2/datasets/SHARED_VIEWS/tables/config_vw/data` for the view, it is giving below error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Cannot list a table of type VIEW.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Cannot list a table of type VIEW.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Please suggest how to access BQ view using REST API ?

Regards,
San

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected that you cannot fetch data from a view using [tabledata.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list) REST API.

VIEW is essentially a "saved query", which you need to make a query to materialize it into a table before you can use [tabledata.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list) to fetch its data.

E.g., you can use [jobs.insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) API to run a query like

```sql
CREATE TABLE SHARED_VIEWS.materailized_config_vw
AS SELECT * FROM SHARED_VIEWS.config_vw
```

Then you can read SHARED_VIEWS.materailized_config_vw using tabledata.list.